# Creating Lucene Index in a Database - Apache Lucene

Tags: lucene, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using grails searchable plugin. It creates index files on a given location. Is there any way in searchable plugin to create Lucene index in a database?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no.

You can probably attempt to implement your own [format](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/fileformats.html) but this would require a **lot** of effort.

Comment: If there are scale-able environments(multiple environments for load balancing) than how lucene will work ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you have meant by your question, but I'd suggest you to read [this article](http://searchhub.org/2009/09/02/scaling-lucene-and-solr/) which covers Lucene/Solr scalability topic in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in Lucene, but I know that it is optimized to offer fast search over the filesystem. So it would be theoretically possible to build a Lucene index over the database, but the main feature of lucene (being a VERY fast search engine) would be lost.

Comment: +1 Only local file-system based directories offer acceptable performance.

Answer (score 1):

As a point of interest, [Compass](http://compass-project.org/) supported storage of a Lucene index in a database, using a [JdbcDirectory](http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.0.1/api/org/apache/lucene/store/jdbc/JdbcDirectory.html).  This was, as far as I can figure, just a bad idea.

Compass, by the way, is now defunct, having been [replaced by ElasticSearch](http://www.kimchy.org/the_future_of_compass/).